# Angular 5- PDF document , download and show in the new window

Tags: angular, pdf, iframe

I am working Angular as Front End and I am getting data from REST Full Web Service.
1) I need to show the pdf file in new window of the web browser which I am getting data from the web service as base 64.

**Problem:** I am able to download the file but when i try to open the file in new window its showing (ERROR: Failed to load the pdf content). Here is my code:

service:

```
this.http.get('https://localhost:44364/api/v1/source/GetImage/parameter1/animal.pdf', { responseType:'arraybuffer' })
    .subscribe(response => {
    var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    this.content=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileURL);
});
```

HTML: In HTML i used IFRAME to display pdf data

```
iframe class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src" width="640" height="390" [src]="content"
```

Could any one please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In order to download the pdf file, you can try this below code. You cannot open the pdf file in desktop.

```
  this.httpClient.get('../assets/sample.pdf', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
    }).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);

      const file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
      /*const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = fileURL;
      link.download = 'sample.pdf';
      link.click();*/
      if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
           window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileURL.split(':')[1] + '.pdf');
      } else {
           window.open(fileURL);
      }
   });
```

}

Comment: Hi Suresh,  I want to open it in new window of the browser (window.open()), instead of downloading the file.

Comment: hi suresh, I tried the above code , the same window.open(fileURL) opening the pdf file in new window , but it still throwing the same error(failed o load PDF document) , if you have any idea could you please help me.

Comment: might be issue with pdf file. you can try with other pdf files

Comment: Hi Suresh, I think there is a problem in my pdf data. now i m able to recify my error but still cannot able to write the data to pdf. form the webservice I am getting the base 64  string : const httpOptions = {
        'responseType'  : 'string' as 'json'
      };
       this.http.get<string>('https://..animal.pdf',httpOptions).subscribe((response)=>{
    const a=atob(response);
       const file=new Blob([a],{type:'application/pdf'})
       const fileURL=window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
         window.open(fileURL);

Comment: what is the better way to deal with the pdf's is I have to get the PDF file from the web api instead of base 64 string or byte[] array. could you please suggest me

Comment: https://ng2-pdf-viewer-empmqw.stackblitz.io/ this is the stack bliz for my demo and in console you can see the pdf generation.

Comment: working also without extencion url, great suggestion :) thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

If you want do display a base 64 pdf you can use my component 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-viewer

It works with angular 2+ and it renders Base 64 images, URL Images and Base 64 PDFs, it's easy to implement, you just have to:

1) Run `npm install ng2-image-viewer --save`

2) Add these codes on your angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
     "../node_modules/ng2-image-viewer/imageviewer.scss"
],
"scripts": [
     "../node_modules/ng2-image-viewer/imageviewer.js"
],
```

3) Import ImageViewerModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // Specify your library as an import
    ImageViewerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4) Now you can use it as you wish:

```
<!-- You can now use your library component in app.component.html -->
<h1>
  Image Viewer
</h1>
<app-image-viewer [images]="['iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', 'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?random']"
[idContainer]="'idOnHTML'"
[loadOnInit]="true"></app-image-viewer>
```

Here is a demo of it [Ng2-Image-Viewer Showcase](https://brenoprata10.github.io/ng2-image-viewer/)

For more info you can check the link above :)

Answer (score 0):

If opening the file in a new window is not a problem, and you are using a modern browser like chrome, they can automatically handle pdf,

```
window.open(URL, '_blank');
```

else if you need to do all this work manually you can use npm packages like,

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer
```

if you don't have much requirement from pdf viewer like export mail download etc, you can use HTML elements

```
<embed src="file_name.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

Make sure to change the width and height for your needs. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Akshay, Thanks for reply . first I tried to open the pdf using window.open(URL,'_blank') ,it throwing the same error like(ERROR:Failed to load the pdf document. in browser)

Comment: Copy that URL and paste in a new tab if its a valid pdf URL it should open.
e.g https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf
try pasting above link in new tab